# VBA Excel Property of a Class2 as object from Class1

Tags: class, vba, properties

I am struggling to make the thing working using VBA Class modules

First class module is tDate

```
'--- Class1 tDate
Public d as Integer
Public m as Integer
Public y as Integer
'--- some get/let properties for d,m,y
```

Second class module is tRate

```
'--- Class2 tRate
Public pDate1 as New tDate
Public dValue as Double
'--- Now i'm trying to code properties 

Public Property Get FirstDate() As tDate
    FirstDate = pDate1
End Property

Public Property Set FirstDate(vDate As tDate)
    pDate1 = vDate  ' <----  ???
End Property
```

In simple module I have the following sub to test the class

```
Sub test()
    Dim myDate As New tDate 
    Dim r1 As New tRate

    myDate.SetDate "20/10/1996"

    r1.FirstDate = myDate ' <-----  "Compile error : Invalid use of property"
End Sub
```

What is the best solution to link small class1 object as a property of bigger class2?

Thank you!!
Nicholas

---

Problem resolved using Set :

```
Public Property Get FirstDate() As tDate
    Set FirstDate = pDate1
End Property

Public Property Set FirstDate(vDate As tDate)
    Set pDate1 = vDate 
End Property
```

and here as well :

```
 Set r1.FirstDate = myDate
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set` to assign an object to a variable.

```
Set r1.FirstDate = myDate
```

Comment: Thanks Serg! You are right. I shall use `Set` everywhere :

    Public Property Get FirstDate() As tDate
        Set FirstDate = pDate1
    End Property
    
    Public Property Set FirstDate(vDate As tDate)
        Set pDate1 = vDate 
    End Property

and here as well :

     Set r1.FirstDate = myDate